# Incorrect syntax near '='. Getting the error

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT [CountryName] 
FROM [tablename]
ORDER BY [CountryName] = 'India' DESC,
         CountryName ASC
```

The above query is working fine in SQL, but it's showing syntax error in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. New to SQL Server

Comment: "SQL Server ORDER BY" in google would solve this for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"working fine in sql"? SQL on it's own doesn't do anything; I assume you mean it is working fine on a different RDBMS (which one, I don't know).

Assuming India should be at the bottom, the correct way to do this, however, would be to use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT [CountryName] 
FROM [tablename]
ORDER BY CASE [CountryName] WHEN 'India' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC,
         CountryName ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what are you trying to achieve...

You cannot have a predicate in an `ORDER BY`. Do you want to select only the rows for `countryName = 'India'`-  then you need to put this into a `WHERE` clause - not the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT [CountryName] 
FROM [tablename]
WHERE [CountryName] = 'India'
ORDER BY [CountryName] DESC, CountryName ASC
```

And which "sql" are  you talking about that supposedly works fine with this code of yours?? SQL is just the **query language** - used by many database systems - but I'm pretty sure your syntax isn't valid in ANSI/ISO standard SQL either....